# Removing Data From ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to remove data from ElasticSearch. I have deleted my indexes. However, that doesn't seem to actually remove the data itself. The other stuff I've seen points to the [Delete by Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) feature. However, I'm not even sure what to query on. I know my indexes. Essentially, I'd like to figure out how to do a

```
DELETE FROM [Index]
```

From PostMan in Chrome. However, I'm not having any luck. It seems like no matter what I do, the data hangs around. Thus far, I've successfully deleted the indexes by using the DELETE HTTP Verb in PostMan and using a url like:

```
   http://localhost:9200/[indexName]
```

However, that doesn't seem to actually remove the data (aka docs) themselves.

Comment: I check this with postman and got reposne as "{
  "acknowledged": true
}" If you see this acknowledged response don't worry. The index is removed from elastic.

Answer (score 512, accepted):

You can delete using `cURL` or visually using one of the many tools that open source enthusiasts have created for Elasticsearch.

**Using cURL**

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index/type/documentID
```

e.g.

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/shop/product/1
```

You will then receive a reply as to whether this was successful or not. You can delete an entire index or types with an index also, you can delete a type by leaving out the document ID like so -

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/shop/product
```

If you wish to delete an index -

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/shop
```

If you wish to delete more than one index that follows a certain naming convention (note the `*`, a wildcard), -

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/.mar*
```

**Visually**

There are various tools as mentioned above, I wont list them here but I will link you to one which enables you to get started straight away, located [here](https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro). This tool is called Cerebro (former KOPF), to connect to your host please click on the logo on top left hand corner and enter the URL of your cluster.

Once connected you will be able to administer your entire cluster, delete, optimise and tune your cluster.

Comment: is there any way I can delete 3 doc's of which id I know.

Comment: @JayeshJain to my current knowledge, no. You could put 3 modified curl -XDELETE commands into a bash script and execute or run 3 one after the other.

Comment: @JayeshJain so curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index/type/docid1 // curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index/type/docid2 // curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index/type/docid3

Comment: i did it the same way.but I was just thinking if there is a smarter way of deleting multiple docs. I could use term if I knew the field. But In this scenario,i just need to delete docs by their id. Thx anyways

Comment: How can I delete an index with an invalid character, e.g., logstash-eu-%{customer}-2016.11.22. I want to delete ALL indices logstash-eu-%{customer}-* or logstash-eu-%*

Comment: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

Comment: @Green your elasticsearch instance may not be listening on localhost?

Comment: Shouldn’t there be a space between the -X and DELETE ?

Answer (score 583):

If you ever need to delete all the indexes, this may come in handy:

```
curl -X DELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all'
```

Powershell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -method DELETE http://localhost:9200/_all
```

Note:
**This will delete all data, including your x-pack access credentials and Kibana dashboard and visualizations**

Comment: this is very useful for development and needing to reset back to scratch (empty) database. Thanks!!

Comment: in your bash_profile create an alias for this command and it will come in handy for development.

Comment: 'Wildcard expressions or all indices are not allowed'

Comment: Note that this will delete all data, including your x-pack access credentials.

Comment: This is also deleting Kibana dashboards and visualizations

Comment: I'm using AWS ES and when I run this command, I seem unable to recreate index patterns in Kibana UI.

Comment: After doing this on a local Docker instance I'm getting an internal server error when going to http://localhost:5601/ (`"Error: Internal Server Error\n    at HapiResponseAdapter.toInternalError (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/http/router/response_adapter.js:61:19)\n    at Router.handle (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/http/router/router.js:177:34)\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n    at handler (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/http/router/router.js:124:50)\n    at exports.Manager.execute [...cut...]"`)

Comment: Thanks, I could regex and delete the specific group using [curl -X DELETE 'http://localhost:9200/csvtest*']

Comment: come in handy ... to remove everything: dashboards, x-pack access credentials

Comment: Does deleting all indices equate to deleting all documents?  Will there be any data left after running this command?

Comment: This answer still doesn't work in `8.9.0`, same error as @ZurabWeb

Answer (score 63):

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html) (or [The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_deleting_an_index.html)) says, that you can also use the next query to delete *all* indices:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/*'
```

And there's an important note:

> For some, the ability to delete all your data with a single command is a very scary prospect. If you want to eliminate the possibility of an accidental mass-deletion, you can set the following to `true` in your `elasticsearch.yml`:
>
> `action.destructive_requires_name: true`

Answer (score 38):

You have to send a `DELETE` request to

```
http://[your_host]:9200/[your_index_name_here]
```

You can also delete a single document:

```
http://[your_host]:9200/[your_index_name_here]/[your_type_here]/[your_doc_id]
```

I suggest you to use [elastichammer](http://elastichammer.exploringelasticsearch.com/).

After deleting you can look up if the index still exists with the following URL: `http://[your_host]:9200/_stats/`

Good luck!

Comment: what is the way to delete indices older than 10 days ? I can not use curator because my server is not support.

Comment: After deleting the index, you can also check its presence at `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices`

Answer (score 30):

```
#list all index:       curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v
```

[image]

```
#delete index:         curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/index_name'
#delete all indices:   curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/_all'
#delete document   :   curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/index_name/type_name/document_id'
```

> Install [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana). Kibana has a smarter dev tool which helps to build query easily.

[image]

Comment: what is the way to delete indices older than 10 days ? I can not use curator because my server is not support.

Answer (score 21):

Deleting the index will delete the mapping and type along. you can delete all rows by the following query

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_query?pretty' -d'
{
   "query": { 
      "match_all": 
   }
}'
```

However for above query you need to install delete-by-query plugin as of Elasticsearch's 2.0.0-beta1  delete-by-query was removed from main api

```
Install delete-by-query plugin

sudo bin/plugin install delete-by-query
```

For more

http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-delete-elasticsearch-data-records-by-dsl-query/

Comment: Both before and after installing the plugin and restarting ES, I get "No handler found for uri and method".

Comment: This does not work in Elasticsearch 6+. Use _delete_by_query instead.

Answer (score 18):

```
curl -X DELETE 'https://localhost:9200/_all'
```

Change `http` to `https` if you are using SSL certificate in you application

Answer (score 15):

You can delete the index by Kibana Console:

[image: Console Icon]

To get all index:

```
GET /_cat/indices?v
```

To delete a specific index:

```
DELETE /INDEX_NAME_TO_DELETE
```

Answer (score 12):

To list down the indices
`curl -L localhost:9200/_cat/indices`

`9200` default port[change the port if using some other port]

You will likely find all indices starting with `logstash-yyyy-mm-dd` format(logstash-*)

You can see all the indices and use

To delete the indices and data trigger following command.

`curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index_name` (Which will remove the data and indices both).

Answer (score 11):

You can delete an index in python as follows

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost', 'port':'9200'}])

es.index(index='grades',doc_type='ist_samester',id=1,body={
    "Name":"Programming Fundamentals",
    "Grade":"A"
})

es.indices.delete(index='grades')
```

Answer (score 11):

simplest way !

```
Endpoint :
http://localhost:9201/twitter/_delete_by_query

Payload :
{
  "query": { 
    "match": {
      "message": "some message"
    }
  }
}
```

where `twitter` is the index in elastic search

ref ; https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Answer (score 11):

> **1. Delete API**

**Removes a document from the specified index.**

```
DELETE /<index>/_doc/<_id>
```

Example:

```
DELETE http://localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_doc/1
```

*Reference : [ES Guide >> Delete API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html)*

> **2. Delete by query API**

**Deletes documents that match the specified query.**

Example:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
      "match": {
           "user.id": "elkbee"
      }
   }
}
```

*Reference : [ES Guide >> Delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete.html)*

Answer (score 8):

For mass-delete by query you may use special [delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/docs-delete-by-query.html):

```
$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_query' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

## In history that API was deleted and then reintroduced again

Who interesting it has long history.

1. In first version of that answer I refer to documentation of elasticsearch [version 1.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/docs-delete-by-query.html). In it that functionality was marked as deprecated but works good.
2. In [elasticsearch version 2.0 it was moved to separate plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/plugins-delete-by-query.html). And even reasons why it became plugin [explained](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/delete-by-query-plugin-reason.html).
3. And it [again appeared in core API in version 5.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.0/plugins-delete-by-query.html)!

Comment: Be careful using delete by query. Its deprecated for a major reason. OutOfMemoryError!

Comment: Sure. But you may spy if it happened for you or you have anough memory.

Comment: This does not deprecated anymore: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/docs-delete-by-query.html

Answer (score 7):

You can delete either whole index,doc-type or a perticular id data.
these are the three ways:

1. curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index_name
2. curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index_name/doc-type
3. curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index_name/doc-type/documentId

and if you wish to delete all the index then go for wildcard.

Comment: Hi, i hope before executing queries you started your elastic search and make sure by default it binds to all local addresses. and instead of localhost you can also use your  IP address. like 10.80.15.45:9200 And once check your ES setting I can think to check in network.bind_host and make sure it is either not set or is set to 0.0.0.0 or ::0 or to the correct IP address for your network.

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to delete logstash index and searched a lot regarding different tools like curl. But found the solution at the end. 
Login into Kibana. Go to Dev Tools tab and type `DELETE /logstash-*` in query field and hit green arrow button. if you get "acknowledged": true in response that means the data has been cleared.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! i tried many other options- this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can **delete one or more indices, which really deletes their files from disk**. For example:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/$INDEXNAME
```

Where `$INDEXNAME` can be an index name (e.g. `users_v2`), N indices separated by comma (e.g. `users_v2,users_v3`). An index pattern (e.g. `users_*`) or `_all`, also works, unless it's blocked in the config via `action.destructive_requires_name: true`.

**Deleting individual documents is possible, but this won't immediately purge them**. A delete is only a soft delete, and documents are really removed during [segment merges](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/index-modules-merge.html). You'll find lots of details about segments and merges in [this presentation](https://sematext.com/blog/solr-optimize-is-not-bad-for-you-lucene-solr-revolution/). It's about Solr, but merges are from Lucene, so you have the same options in Elasticsearch.

Back to the API, you can either delete individual documents by ID (provide a routing value if you index with routing):

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/users_v2/_doc/user1
```

Or by query:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:9200/users_v2/_delete_by_query -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "description_field": "bad user"
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of good answers here, but there is also something i'd like to add:

- If you are running on **AWS ElasticSearch service**, **you can´t drop/delete indexes**. ***Instead of delete indexes, you must reindex them***.

Comment: Just deleted an index on AWS ElasticSearch, my domain is running ES 5.1.

Comment: On AWS ES you can't open/close indexes - that requires reindexing. You can, however, delete indexes. I've only done it through the Kibana console, but it definitely works.

Answer (score 5):

I used Dev Tools to delete data

```
POST <index_name>/_delete_by_query
  {
   "query": {
       "match_all": {}
    }
 }
```

Example

```
POST vehicle-data/_delete_by_query
      {
       "query": {
           "match_all": {}
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also delete the index using DELETE action in 'elasticsearch head' ([Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/elasticsearch%20head) ). Add it to your chrome and connect it to your host. There you will find all your indices and if you click on actions button below the index you want to delete, you will find a DELETE option in the drop down. click on it and enter DELETE in the pop-up. Your index will be deleted. 'Elasticsearch head' extension is an easy way to view and manage your indices and data.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use chrome extension elasticsearch-head to delete index

Answer (score 1):

Say I need to delete an index `filebeat-7.6.2-2020.04.30-000001` and I performed it using a curl DELETE option (`curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/filebeat-7.6.2-2020.04.30-000001?pretty"`) and results in an **authentication** problem as below;

```
{
  "error" : {
    "type" : "security_exception",
    "reason" : "missing authentication credentials for REST request [/filebeat-7.6.2-2020.04.30-000001?pretty]"
  },
  "status" : 401
}
```

Here you should authenticate the curl request using the username and password you have provided for Elasticsearch. Try then

`curl -X DELETE -u myelasticuser:myelasticpassword "localhost:9200/filebeat-7.6.2-2020.04.30-000001?pretty"`

will results in **{
  "acknowledged" : true
}**.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the `delete_by_query` [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67395927/1421940), if you want to quickly delete all records in a given index it may be also important to set the `scroll_size` and `conflicts` parameters.

- **Scroll size**

  - It is useful to use a small scroll size to avoid request timeouts while trying to delete many documents at the same time.
- **Conflicts**

  - It is useful to ignore conflicts during batch deletions, because version conflicts are common if you are deleting too many records at once.

---

```
 POST http://localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_delete_by_query?scroll_size=100&conflicts=proceed
 {
   "query": {
       "match_all": {}
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `curl`:

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'http://<username>:<password>@<url>:9200/<index name>/<doc type>/<document id>
```

Or if you do not want to set the username and password at URL, then can also try this curl:

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'http://<url>:9200/<index name>/<doc type>/<document id>' --header 'Authorization: Basic <Base64 encoded username:password>'
```

After executing the response body will contains a `result` field. If this field's value is `deleted`, then it means that the document deleted successfully.

In this `curl` I assumed that you have configured your elastic to use `http`. If you are using `https`, simply change the protocol to `https`.

Answer (score 0):

A python script in order to delete all indexes:

```
import requests
import json

ES_HOST = "http://localhost:9200"
ES_URL = f"{ES_HOST}/_cat/indices?format=json"

indexes = requests.get(ES_URL).content
indexes = json.loads(index.decode())

for i in index:
    index_name = i['index']
    content = requests.delete(f"{ES_HOST}/{index_name}").content
    print(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Kibana** as a tool for viewing and searching elastic search data and I recommend it based on good user experience.

Following queries would help remove data from elastic search -

`Case 1:` If you know the id of that data row:

```
DELETE /index_name/_doc/{id}
```

`Case 2:` Delete based on a column value:
Suppose I have a column named `abc`.

Now I have to get `_id` field based in column_name to finally delete for that row.

```
GET /uts_checkout_configurations/_search { "query" : { "constant_score" : { "filter" : { "bool": { "must": {"exists": {"field": "ABC"}} } } } } }
```

Finally you would get your data with `_id` as one the fields in it.

Delete based on that -

```
DELETE /index_name/_doc/{_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete all red indices you can execute:

```
es_host=127.0.0.1:9210
curl -s "$es_host/_cat/indices?v" |  grep red | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f3 | xargs -I '{}' curl -XDELETE $es_host/{}
```

Answer (score 0):

The year is 2023, I came across this question as I had the same problem, however, I needed to remove an item only from an index.

Scenario data:

> **Index name**: requisitions-index 
> **Item Id I needed to remove**:
> 3d70b8eb-0889-445e-9e17-d5d96a97febc 
> **Item type**: _doc

CURL command used:

```
curl --request DELETE \
  --url http://localhost:9201/requisicoes-index/_doc/3d70b8eb-0889-445e-9e17-d5d96a97febc \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic AWthc6GpYzpjvGFuZ2RhXW==' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Remembering that the Elasticsearch instance required authentication, so I sent the authentication data using BASIC in the Insomnia tool

Details in the images below:

[image]

Insomnia client - for CURL DELETE command:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**: *If you want to delete the index and its document too then*,

**command** : `DELETE /INDEX_NAME_TO_DELETE`

**example** : `DELETE student` here student is index name.

**Case 2**: *if you want delete only documents not index then,*

**command**:

```
POST INDEX_NAME/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

**Example** :

```
POST students/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

**Note** : Use the **POST**  method in case 2.