# elastic search can I delete all the data in an index

Tags: elasticsearch

First of all, I have already checked this question
[Removing Data From ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924300/removing-data-from-elasticsearch)

It's not good for me because the answers there are talking about how to delete the whole index., which is different from my question.

my question is that i want to delete the whole document inside one index, but without deleting the index.

i tried to do the flush command, but it doesn't delete anything.

thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to delete all documents from index?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli which interface do you use? http or any client api etc..

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to delete the documents but keep your index, then you may use the [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.1/plugins-delete-by-query.html) plugin (if you are using ES 2.x) otherwise you may just use the [delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-delete-by-query.html) (if you're using ES 1.7.x or earlier).

So if you're using ES 2.x, first install the plugin with the command below and restart ES

```
bin/plugin install delete-by-query
```

Then you can delete all your documents with the following curl

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/index/_query?q=*
```

Comment: Have you been able to try it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can follow the [Delete by Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query) section on documentation:

let's say that your index is named 'index_test'. So, you can send a POST request to your index_url + '_delete_by_query', so the content (document) of your index will be deleted but the index itself will be preserved:

```
curl -X POST http://elasticAddress:9200/index_test/_delete_by_query
```

With this, you will not lose your visualization content as the index is preserved, but the document (content) is updated.